# Current favicon looks like flag of Turkey

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, logo, favicon

I just noticed this in the sidebar:

> [image]

Now compare with Turkey flag:

> [image]

So I  was wondering "New site for Turkey, eh?"

Can the favicon please be changed? Either plain "C" or other background, not red?

Comment: I can't see any white star in the favicon...

Comment: @JanDvorak the star is small, the "C" is very similar to the carved moon. ;)

Comment: I don't have such association...

Answer (score 8):

While I do see the similarity, I disagree that it’s easy to confuse the two. The backgrounds have noticeably different shades of red, and I’m not sure how you could mistake an italicized, centered ‘C’ for a left-aligned crescent moon and star.

Comment: Not to mention the "C" is in a chat bubble not a rectangle. As chat bubbles are very uncommon on flags I have to agree, what we have now is fine. ;)

Comment: I would like to see the Craft 'C' a little bigger. I think that would help diferentiate it from the flag of Turkey (which it does look quite a bit like)

Comment: thats exactly what a flag plagiarizer would say brandon :)

Answer (score 4):

> Q: How unhealthy is a doner kebab?

Something like this didn't come up yet – so I don't think our favicon did cause that much confusion so far. Other than our "Craft" Community on g+, which attracts DIY people every now and then :D

Comment: ...and here I thought doner kebabs were German since our local doner place is called the Berliner. Thanks for the inadvertent education.

Comment: @matt there are probably more Döner shops in Berlin as there are in turkey. I've heard that they only sell it in turkey to please all the tourists :D

Comment: I believe that doner kebabs were invented by a Turkish guy living in Germany. And now they're a staple in Indian take-aways across Europe. @MattStein.